# tf.keras.layers.pop() doesn't work, but tf.keras._layers.pop() does

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to pop the last layer of the model. So I use the `tf.keras.layers.pop()`, but it doesn't work.

```
base_model.summary()
```

[image]

```
base_model.layers.pop()

base_model.summary()
```

[image]

When I use `tf.keras._layers.pop()`, it works.

```
base_model.summary()
```

[image]

```
base_model._layers.pop()
base_model.summary()
```

[image]

I don't find docs about this usage. Could someone help explain this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree this is confusing. The reason is that `model.layers` returns a shallow copy of the layers list so:

The tldr is dont use `model.layers.pop()` to remove the last layer. Instead we should create a new model with all but the last layer. Perhaps something like this:

```py
new_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(base_model.layers[:-1])
```

Checkout this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22479) for more details

Answer (score 5):

@Stewart_R clearly shows the solution to the problem :)

Let me just put a simple code with the solution.

```py
loaded_model = keras.models.load_model(fname)
    
# remove the last 2 layers
sliced_loaded_model = Sequential(loaded_model.layers[:-2])
    
# set trainable=False for the layers from loaded_model
for layer in sliced_loaded_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
    
# add new layers
sliced_loaded_model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))  # trainable=True is default
sliced_loaded_model.add(Dense(1))
    
# compile
sliced_loaded_model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=[])
    
# fit
...
```